# How would I bind a cookie to a TLS session in IIS/OWIN to make channel bound cookies?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, owin, fido-u2f

Channel bound cookies prevent the concept of bearer tokens, and [bind a cookie to a specific TLS channel.](http://www.browserauth.net/channel-bound-cookies)

How would this be implemented in OWIN, ASP.NET 5, or ASP.NET 4.x?

Comment: I see this is in early stage still (only chrome supports that, and even then with a flag), so I doubt that right now there are some ready-made implementations for asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported in OWIN/Katana (it didn't exist yet). We're working on it for ASP.NET Core but it's not ready yet. See
https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/31 and linked bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Where can I put a request in for OWIN/Katana to support FIDO UAF and U2F (and hopefully get certified) https://fidoalliance.org/certification/fido-certified/

Comment: For what it's worth, Chrome and Safari support U*F standards, and IE will be skipping them in favor of FIDO 2.0 Web Services.

Comment: You can request it here: http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic, but be aware that there is not currently any new feature work happening for Katana.

Comment: Thanks for setting expectations... is this a permanent halt, is there a new focus, or what is the best direction I should take?

Comment: New feature work is focused in Asp.Net Core. I'd recommend migrating when it releases here soon (or before that if you're brave).